# Understanding PagingSource's getRefreshKey

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, android-paging-3

I migrated from Paging 2 to Paging 3 library and now I use the `PagingSource` to load pages of data from the server. But I have trouble understanding the `getRefreshKey` method that has to be overriden there. I found some code samples how to implement it depending on the key used to fetch subsequent pages but I still don't get it. Based on these samples I wrote the following code:

```
override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Pair<String, String>, User>): Pair<String, String>? {
    return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
        state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.prevKey
    }
}
```

But it doesn't change a thing if I make it to always return null:

```
override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Pair<String, String>, User>): Pair<String, String>? = null
```

So is there a reason why I can't just choose the simplest solution possible? Or is there a use case that I don't see?

Answer (score 15):

So, this would be the difference:

Say you have your working list. A user is scrolling the list and there is some change in the list (the data was updated lets say). Then:

Case when getRefreshKey() returns null always:
As your data is updated, there will be a new pair of PagingSource and PagingData, meaning that the paging lib. would need to reload the list. If getRefreshKey() returns null, then it will not know what page was last accessed and will return the user to the start of the list (as the key for position will be decided by the key in load()).

On the other hand, if getRefreshKey() is implemented properly, then:
paging lib. will know the last accessed position and the list will not jump to the top. Instead it will show the last accessed page.

Answer (score 2):

As per the information [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource)

> `getRefreshKey()` provides a `key` used for the initial load for the next `pagingSource` due to invalidation of the existing `pagingSource`. The `key` is provided to `load` via `LoadParams.key`.
> The last accessed `position` can be retrieved via `state.anchorPosition`, which is typically the top-most or bottom-most item in the `viewport` due to access being triggered by binding items as they scroll into `view`.

and the description of `Key` states that

> `key` passed to `load` after invalidation used for initial `load` of the next generation. The `key` returned by `getRefreshKey` should load pages centered around user's current viewport. If the correct `key` cannot be determined, `null` can be returned to allow `load` decide what `default key` to use.

Here, `load` is the `Loading API` for `PagingSource`.

Now I'm not about a use case which makes a difference about whether or not you should be passing a `null` key always, but it doesn't mention any disadvantage of passing `null` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource) and it states that `load` can decide a `default key` in case of a `null` key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was familiar with the documentation but I still don't know what difference choosing 'null' makes and as you also mentioned it doesn't mention any disadvantages.

Comment: oh, hopefully someone can explain better :)